# Honours Project / Sound Replacement For A Video Game

Tags: honours, game, video-games

Hi all,

I have just started my 4th year honours project and i am looking for someone who is designing or remaking/modding a game so that i can replace/create the audio for my honours project, also feedback would be required and contact so that you can tell me what kind of sounds, the feel etc for the sounds. this is purely for my university honours project. i have tried several places and modders/ designers but with no luck at all.

even if you have done a redesign or a mod of a game that you would like the sound redone or created for it contact me and i would be happy to do it for my honours project.

i have been trying all summer to find such a person but with no luck, now i have only a week to find someone, worried doesn't quite cover it.

If you have any advice such as websites or links so on please post them. If you have such a game that you wouldn't mind me doing please get in touch!!

Many Regards

Duncan

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [Source SDK](http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SDK_Docs) (Valve softwares modding engine) - If I remember correctly there are a few maps that are freely available e.g. one of the first levels in Half Life 2. Basically you can replace all for this level, and add some of your own. I am pretty sure that UDK and unity have similar levels available to play with.

Answer (score 1):

Audiokinetic has CUBE, which is  integrated with WWise (there is a WWise session available on their website). Some of the scripting is a little crude but it allows you to replace sounds within the game and play around with WWise at the same time.

http://www.audiokinetic.com/index.php?option=com_facileforms&Itemid=143&ff_contentid=49&ff_form=39

Comment: you also might be able to find a project over at http://www.moddb.com/jobs that is in need of sound work. There's also some really nice people over at gameaudioforum.com who might be of some assistance as well. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, but you don't have to work on a mod for a game to get your own sound design in there. It is probably WAY more work to do it that way. If it is befitting, you could just take all the sounds out of a current game (a friend of mine did his senior project with Braid) and replace them with your own. At least then, you aren't reliant on someone else who might not have the same amount of energy and motivation invested in the project. A ton of games have their engines and editors and stuff available to the public.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to be THAT guy, but if you're looking for a project to do sound on, I would go somewhere else than a hang out for sound designers. Check out Moddb.com or reddit.com/r/gamedev, you're going to get a lot more bites going to places where game developers spend their time.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply's so far, the problem with doing it in an engine myself is that it must be for someone, e.g you want the sound done for x-lvl of a game, or redo the sound for say a game such as final fantasy, you get the idea i'm sure. So i need to have a designer who wants the sound redone.
thanks for the links fuzzysounds i will check them out shortly.

If anyone have such a project please contact me.even if it is not complete eg, as long as the sound could be replaced and i could get feedback.

thanks